# Rails 4 Devise, with after_sign_in_path_for(resource) always redirect to Show action of Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm stuck with the method after_sign_in_path_for of devise, this is the thing...
I have two Models **Users** and **AdminUsers** I'm using the **active_admin** gem

my **routes.rb** file, looks like this:

```
devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
scope "(:locale)", locale: /es|en/ do
        devise_for :users, path_names: { sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout', 
                                    password: 'password', confirmation: 'confirmation', unlock: 'unlock', 
                                    registration: 'registration', sign_up: 'sign_up' }
    devise_scope :user do
      get "login", to: "devise/sessions#new"
    end
get 'dashboard/index'
end
```

OK... in my application_controller.rb, I tryed this codes:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      case resource
          when AdminUser
            #admin_root_path 
            '/admin/dashboard'
            puts'in admin_root_path'
          when User 
            #dashboard_index_path 
            '/dashboard/index'
            puts'in dashboard_index_path'
        else super
        end
      puts 'resource Of AplicationController: ' + resource.class.to_s

  end

  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    root_path
  end
```

As you can see, i have some **puts** just to check in my console if my **case** works... and it does, It actually works, this is my console:
I'm trying to login as **AdminUser**, to the **admin_root_path** of active_admin

```
Started POST "/admin/login?locale=es" for ::1 at 2015-04-14 12:46:51 -0400
Processing by ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
....
....
in admin_root_path
resource of AplicationController: AdminUser
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/admin/users/2?locale=es
Completed 302 Found in 113ms (ActiveRecord: 1.8ms)
```

As you can see, Devise redirect me to the Show page of the current_admin_user.

And here is the console if I try to log in as a User:

```
Started POST "/es/users/login" for ::1 at 2015-04-14 12:51:18 -0400
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
...
...
in dashboard_index_path
resource of AplicationController: User
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/es/users/2
Completed 302 Found in 106ms (ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)
```

In the two scenarios Devise is doing the same... redirecting to the show action of each Model, I already tryed to put this code in a custom registrations_controller.rb and the same...
Maybe I'm missing something obvious, I'm not expert in Devise, does anyone has an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

The relevant results of `rake routes` command

```
....
....
edit_admin_user_password GET   /admin/password/edit(.:format)                 active_admin/devise/passwords#edit

admin_root GET     /admin(.:format)    admin/dashboard#index
....
....
admin_dashboard GET  /admin/dashboard(.:format)    admin/dashboard#index
....
....
dashboard_index GET    (/:locale)/dashboard/index(.:format)   dashboard#index {:locale=>/es|en/}
root GET    /    visitors#index
```

Comment: please run `rake routes` in terminal and check the paths. also paste the result here.

Comment: Done, please let me know if you need something else, I just post the most relevant routes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try this:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  if resource.class == AdminUser
    admin_root_path 
  elsif resource.class == User
    dashboard_index_path 
  end
end
```

Two things to take care: I use `resourse.class` I think this is a typo in the question, and not at the code (because it prints puts). Second, `after_sign_in_path` must return a url, and the last action on your code is a `puts` that returns `nil`.

Also you can try:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  dashboard_index_path 
end
```

To see `after_sign_in_path_for` working for first time. And move forward from this starting point.

If all this doesn't work, please publish `sign_in` and `login` routes.

**Edit**: After reading your post I realize that case doesn't (wrong: it works) work, because case works with `===` and `resource.class === AdminUser` always return false (are diferent objects). You must ask for `resource.class == AdminUser` or `resource.is_a?(AdminUser)`. More of case match [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-case+Expression). I also update the `after_sign_in_path` method.

**Edit 2**
After reading @CJBrew comment, and these experiments at irb:

```
(main) > pp = Person.first
=> "#<Person id: 1 ..."
(main) > pp === Person
=> false
(main) > Person === pp
=> true
(main) > case pp
(main) | when Person  
(main) |   'yes'
(main) | end  
=> "yes"
```

I can say that this code must work fine :

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  case resource
  when User
    root_path
  when AdminUser
    admin_contexts_path
  end
end
```

Because `case` use `===` with the `when` value as object and the case value as param. In this case the first when clause is tested with: `User.===(resource)` or `User === resource`, and the second with `AdminUser.===(resource)`. As `User` and `AdminUser` are Class objects, they use the [`Module#===` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Module.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D). The important thing here is be aware that this method is not commutative, it is a class method which accepts any object as param, and return true if the param is an instance of that class.

Comment: In fact, this works for me:
```def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    case resource
    when User
      root_path
    when AdminUser
      admin_contexts_path
    end
   end```

Comment: Thank you @CJBrew, you make me think and research. And, of course, I update the answer.

Comment: `resource.is_a? User` is more Rails-like

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much Alejandro,

You were right with my **puts** error, actually I'm embarrassed by such an obvious mistake with the **return** of the  method...
For some extrange reason that I don't know the Case doesn't work... It did for the **AdminUser** model, but never for the **User** model... If anybody has an idea, let me know because I hate state with doubts, and right know I'm short of time to workaround...

I did this small changes to the code, and works for me... I know it is a hard and ugly code, but it does the job, maybe later i got some time to make a better code.

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  return dashboard_index_path if resource.class == User
  return admin_root_path
end
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome. I update my answer with the ```case``` no go update.